# Programmatically set TextView gravity right in a TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, gravity

I know this has been asked several times over, but can't seem to get it to work correctly in my situation. I am trying to get the last column to align right in a table that is generated programatically. I know I need to apply the LayoutParams to the row and all the inner children, and I know that I need to set the Gravity to the TextView, not the row, but I have tried all the permutations I can think of and can't seem to get the last column to align right.

Here is my XML layout:

```
<!--Open Hours-->
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/llOpenHourDetail"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/llWebsiteDetail"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:visibility="gone"
   android:weightSum="4">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvOpenHourDetailIcon"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="@string/fa_clock"
       android:textColor="@color/cp_blue" />

   <TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/tlOpenHoursDetail"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then in my activity I have the following code in a loop

```
String currentPeriod = formattedOpen.format(open.getTime()) + " - " +
    formattedClose.format(close.getTime());

TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getBaseContext());
tableRow.setLayoutParams(params);

TextView tvDayOfWeek = new TextView(getBaseContext());
tvDayOfWeek.setText(open.getDisplayName(
    Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()));
tvDayOfWeek.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
tvDayOfWeek.setLayoutParams(params);
tableRow.addView(tvDayOfWeek);

TextView tvPeriodHours = new TextView(getBaseContext());

tvPeriodHours.setText(currentPeriod);
tvPeriodHours.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
tvPeriodHours.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
tvPeriodHours.setLayoutParams(params);
tableRow.addView(tvPeriodHours);

tlOpenHoursDetail.addView(tableRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for `setGravity()` to work you must first modify the width field of your`TextView` as follows in your layout:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Now you should be able to call:

```
tvPeriodHours.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)
```

Comment: The TextView isn't in my XML, just the TableLayout container. I thought I was setting the width when I called tvPeriodHours.setLayoutParams(params) and params was defined as MATCH_PARENT. Is my understanding not correct?

Comment: Oh I gotcha; does it work if you specify `TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

Comment: There was no visible change when I updated the code from 

TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

to be

TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: I just noticed that you are trying to call `setGravity` before you call `setLayoutParams`. Try calling `tvPeriodHours.setLayoutParams(params)` right after you create the `TextView`

Comment: Thanks for your help BTW :)

I originally was setting the layoutParams right after initializing the TextView and just switched it back so the code looks like the following. Unfortunately, still no change :(

TextView tvPeriodHours = new TextView(getBaseContext());
tvPeriodHours.setLayoutParams(params);
tvPeriodHours.setText(currentPeriod);
tvPeriodHours.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
tvPeriodHours.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways of doing this.

1. If your TableLayout has a width not based on it's contents (such as if the columns widths are set using `android:stretchColumns`) you can set the TextView width to `match_parent` and then assign the gravity on the TextView using `textView.setGravity(Gravity.END)`.
2. If your TextView width is smaller than the bounds of the TableLayout cell you can call the gravity on the TableRow instead using `tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.END)`.

I have a TableLayout where my TextViews fill the width of the cell but not the height so I'm using:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

To get my text in the very centre of the cell.

In case it helps anyone, I have spent ages trying to get the TextView aligned to the bottom of the cell but nothing seems to work, including `tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)`, no idea why but I have given up and in the centre is fine.